# How to stop threadpool after main function is over in AWS FirehoseAsync putRecordAsync?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, threadpool, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to use AWS Firehose as a log appender. My requirement is to put logs in the firehose in async mode. I have made the log4j appender following this [github repo](https://github.com/awslabs/kinesis-log4j-appender/issues/16).

The problem I am facing is that AWS FirehoseAsync opens multiple threads in the background but when the tasks are over, the main process keeps on running even if there is nothing to execute.

```
public class MainTest {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainTest.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String streamName = "kinesis-firehose stream";
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();

        clientConfiguration.setMaxErrorRetry(5);
        clientConfiguration.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy(PredefinedRetryPolicies.DEFAULT_RETRY_CONDITION,
                PredefinedRetryPolicies.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_STRATEGY, 5, true));
        clientConfiguration.setUserAgentPrefix(AppenderConstants.USER_AGENT_STRING);

        BlockingQueue<Runnable> taskBuffer = new LinkedBlockingDeque<Runnable>(1000);

        ThreadPoolExecutorFactory factory = new ThreadPoolExecutorFactory(3, taskBuffer);
        AmazonKinesisFirehoseAsync kinesisFirehoseAsync = AmazonKinesisFirehoseAsyncClientBuilder
                .standard().withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
                .withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration).withExecutorFactory(factory)
                .withRegion(ApplicationContext.getInstance().getAwsRegion()).build();

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            log.debug("Counter [{}]", i);
            String message = String.valueOf(i);
            ByteBuffer data = ByteBuffer.wrap(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            Record record = new Record().withData(data);
            PutRecordRequest request = new PutRecordRequest().withDeliveryStreamName(streamName).withRecord(record);
            kinesisFirehoseAsync.putRecordAsync(request);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of `1.11.442` Kinesis SDK version there aren't any implementation of AmazonKinesisFirehoseAsync interface other than AmazonKinesisFirehoseAsyncClient. It uses threads to achieve asynchronous operation where threads managed by ExecutorService. You should close the ExecutorService that the client uses.

```
if(kinesisFirehoseAsync instanceof AmazonKinesisFirehoseAsyncClient) {
    AmazonKinesisFirehoseAsyncClient kinesisFirehoseAsyncClient 
            = (AmazonKinesisFirehoseAsyncClient) kinesisFirehoseAsync;
    ExecutorService executorService = kinesisFirehoseAsyncClient.getExecutorService();
    executorService.shutdown();
}
```

At first glance, it might seem bad practice to cast the object but AmazonKinesisFirehoseAsync does not define `getExecutorService` method. Therefore, the only option is to cast the object. Please note that, the implementation might be changed in the future.